# Ordenamento avançado de registros em MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, order-by

Estou tentando ordenar uma query no mysql, porém, as regras de ordenação são um pouco complexas. A minha tabela possui os campos: 'id', 'data', 'id_pai', 'nome'

Há três tipos de registro, na tabela:

***1 - Registro SOLTEIRO**: não estão relacionados a nenhum outro registro da tabela*

***2 - Registro PAI**: Possuem ascendência sobre registros FILHO*

***3 - Registro FILHO**: São descendentes de algum registro PAI*

- Os registros SOLTEIRO e PAI possuem valor ZERO, no campo 'id_pai'.
- Os registros FILHO possuem valor do campo 'id_pai' igual ao valor do campo 'id' de seu PAI.

A ordenação deve seguir as seguintes regras:

***1 -** Ordenar, crescentemente, pelo campo 'data', os registros SOLTEIROs e PAIs* 

***2 -** Quando encontrar um registro PAI, suspende a ordenação pelo critério da etapa 1 e insere seus registros FILHO, ordenados pelo campo 'data'*

***3 -** Retorna ao ponto onde parou quando suspendeu a etapa 1*

**Exemplo:**

Tabela

| id | data | id_pai | nome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 3 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 1 |
| 3 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | PAI 1 |
| 4 | 2020-08-01 | 3 | FILHO 2 |
| 5 | 2020-02-10 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 2 |
| 6 | 2020-06-03 | 3 | FILHO 1 |
| 7 | 2020-05-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 4 |

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    id INT(11),
    data DATE,
    id_pai INT(8),
    nome VARCHAR(20)
);

insert into tabela (id, data, id_pai, nome) values (1, '2020-04-01', 0, 'SOLTEIRO 3'),
(2, '2020-01-01', 0, 'SOLTEIRO 1'),
(3, '2020-02-01', 0, 'PAI 1'),
(4, '2020-08-01', 0, 'FILHO 2'),
(5, '2020-02-10', 0, 'SOLTEIRO 2'),
(6, '2020-06-03', 0, 'FILHO 1'),
(7, '2020-05-01', 0, 'SOLTEIRO 4');
```

Saída ordenada:

| id | data | id_pai | nome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 1 |
| 3 | 2020-02-01 | 0 | PAI 1 |
| 6 | 2020-06-03 | 3 | FILHO 1 |
| 4 | 2020-08-01 | 3 | FILHO 2 |
| 5 | 2020-02-10 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 2 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 3 |
| 7 | 2020-05-01 | 0 | SOLTEIRO 4 |

Comment: Eu acredito que tu precisas implementar uma função de ordenação personalizada para atender tuas necessidades. Tu tentaste implementar uma?

Comment: falta na sua pergunta os comandos `select` que já fez

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma forma de conseguir o resultado desejado é usar o `CASE` na ordem, no caso montei uma string com as regras da ordenação.

Segue a query abaixo:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela as t0
ORDER BY 
  (CASE
       -- Quando não houver filhos e não tiver pai
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is null) 
            and (t0.id_pai = 0) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', 0)
       -- Quando houver filhos
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is not null) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', t0.id)
       -- Quando for filho
       ELSE
          concat(
               (select t2.data from tabela as t2 where t2.id = t0.id_pai)
               , '.'
               , t0.id_pai
               , '.'
               , t0.data
              )

     END
)
```

Veja aqui o exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36557d/1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado da ordenação:

```
id  data    id_pai  nome
2   2020-01-01  0   SOLTEIRO 1
3   2020-02-01  0   PAI 1
6   2020-06-03  3   FILHO 1 / PAI 1
4   2020-08-01  3   FILHO 2 / PAI 1
5   2020-02-10  0   SOLTEIRO 2
1   2020-04-01  0   SOLTEIRO 3
10  2020-05-01  0   SOLTEIRO 6
9   2020-05-01  0   SOLTEIRO 5
7   2020-05-01  0   SOLTEIRO 4
8   2020-05-01  0   PAI 2
11  2020-05-02  8   FILHO 2 / PAI 2
12  2020-05-03  8   FILHO 1 / PAI 2
10  2020-05-02  0   SOLTEIRO 8
```

**Para ver explicitamente a string usada na ordenação** (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36557d/2):

```
SELECT *, (CASE
       -- Quando não houver filhos e não tiver pai
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is null) 
            and (t0.id_pai = 0) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', 0)
       -- Quando houver filhos
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is not null) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', t0.id)
       -- Quando for filho
       ELSE
          concat(
               (select t2.data from tabela as t2 where t2.id = t0.id_pai)
               , '.'
               , t0.id_pai
               , '.'
               , t0.data
              )

     END
)ordem
FROM tabela as t0
ORDER BY 
  (CASE
       -- Quando não houver filhos e não tiver pai
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is null) 
            and (t0.id_pai = 0) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', 0)
       -- Quando houver filhos
       WHEN ((select group_concat(t1.id) from tabela as t1 where t1.id_pai = t0.id) is not null) 
         then concat(t0.data , '.', t0.id)
       -- Quando for filho
       ELSE
          concat(
               (select t2.data from tabela as t2 where t2.id = t0.id_pai)
               , '.'
               , t0.id_pai
               , '.'
               , t0.data
              )

     END
)
```

RESULTADO:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Antes de criticar ou votar contra, comente qual o problema da pergunta ou da resposta, pois dessa forma estará contribuindo com a comunidade.

Comment: Aceita select no Order , já fiz Order by case mas nunca fiz com select (Oracle) , CASE não faz a janta mas esquenta no micro-ondas ...

Comment: A query acaba por ordenar pela data, inicialmente, já que tanto para pai, solteiro e filho, a concatenação começa com o campo 'data' do registro. Na prática, a saída é ordenada pela 'data' e, nos casos de igualdade de 'data', se utiliza outros campos, não chegando no resultado necessário.

Comment: @MarcioMaradei: Não ordena pela data apenas, ele checa a situação e constrói uma ordenação de acordo com as regras solicitadas. Poderia demonstrar uma situação em que ela não funciona? Insira mais dados na tabela (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a69ff3/34) para demonstrar a falha, e depois poste a url do novo fiddle aqui nos comentários que te ajudo a resolver.

Comment: @Motta: A sua resposta está perfeita. Não sei pq, ontem, quando testei em meu servidor, não funcionou direito. Testei novamente e ela funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Na verdade, não estava com domínio da utilização dessa estrutura CASE WHEN, no Order By. Vou aproveitar essa sua luz para me aprofundar no assunto. Valeu!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Comment: Vou testar isto em Oracle !

Comment: @Motta, Boa! Testa depois aqui no comentário se deu certo com Oracle e em qual versão você testou.